# PDO::FETCH_CLASS and ctor_args

Tags: php, pdo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [pass constructor arguments using PDO::FETCH_CLASSTYPE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6686302/pass-constructor-arguments-using-pdofetch-classtype)

How to put arguments in the fetch class object constructor?

## code

```
$sth->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'Fetch_class', ['method' => 'get']);

class Fetch_class extends fclass {
    public function __construct($options=[]){
        print_r($options);
    }
}

class fclass {
    
}
```

## result

```
Array
(
)
```

Comment: there are no suitable solutions in the two questions

Comment: there is also an example in the comments to http://php.net/manual/de/pdostatement.setfetchmode.php

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The correct way to use PDO::FETCH_CLASS:

```
class MyClass
{
    public $id;

    public function MyMethod()
    {
       // do stuff
    }
}

$result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, "MyClass");
foreach($result as $myclass)
{
    echo $myclass->id . ' => ' . $myclass->MyMethod();
}
```

Comment: yes, but how do you pass extra vars to `MyClass` ?